# Parse xml and fetch by attributes

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

I have xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

<string name='Level0'>Beginner</string>
<string name='Level1'>Normal</string>
<string name='Level2'>Hard</string>
<string name='Level3'>Super Hard</string>
```

I want to pull out each item in `<string>` tag.

For now it is my code.

```
var xmlBody = xml.parse(contents);
var names = xmlBody.findAllElements('string');

total.map((node) => node.text).forEach(print); // testing, it returns text
total.map((node) => node.attributes).forEach(print);// testing, it returns attributes

 //Below is what I want to get. 

print(names.attribute('name','Level0').text)); // this is wrong...
```

It might be the basic knowledge of XML parser....

However I cant find the good documents.

Does anyone gives me the hint??

Answer (score 3):

The following code should get you going:

```
  var document = parse(theXml);
  var allStringElements = document.findAllElements('string');

  // dissect the first element...
  var firstElement = allStringElements.first;
  print(firstElement.text);
  print(firstElement.attributes.first.value); // should really search the attributes for the one called 'name', but as there's only one...

  // or do something useful with the whole list
  for (var element in allStringElements) {
    print('${element.attributes.first.value}->${element.text}');
  }
```

The first two lines parse the document and extract the `string` tags as you are doing. This gives a list of elements (actually a lazy iterator...).

An element has `text` (from between the opening and closing tags) and `attributes`, which is another list - this time of all the attributes inside the opening tag.

As there's only one attribute, we can select it with `first` (though it would be better to use `firstWhere` and pass a predicate that selected by name=="name". The next two lines show printing those.

Finally we can loop over the whole list doing something with the key and value of the key-value pair. In this case just print them.

Comment: Did this help? Any other issues?